# Odata Error translating Linq expression at call Contains

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

Is it possible using ASP.NET Web APi OData make similar:

```
List<string> customersTitles = Odata.OrdersService.Select(o=>o.CustomerTitle).Distinct().ToList();

List<Customer> customers = Odata.CustomerService.Where(m => customersTitles .Contains(m.CustomerTitle))
```

Get error:

> Error translating Linq expression to URI: The expression
>   value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]).Contains([10007].CustomerTitle)
>   is not supported.}

API:

```
public class CustomerController : EntitySetController<Customer, int>
{

    [Queryable]
    public override IQueryable<Customer> Get()
    {
        Expression filter = this.QueryOptions.Filter.ToExpression<Customer>();
        return db.Query<Customer>(filter as Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Contains construct is not supported via URIs since the list of strings existing at the client side is not a Server side resource.

Linq2Sql Provider has an innate translation for Contains, which gets translated to IN clause for SQL.

With OData, such a translation is not supported. What you need to build is an expanded query list for your where clause using all the Title values:

Because this does not work:

```
List<Customer> customers = Odata.CustomerService.Where(m => customersTitles .Contains(m.CustomerTitle))
```

the expanded query option helps us in building a query like:

```
List<Customer> customers = Odata.CustomerService.Where(m => m.CustomerTitle == customerTitles[0] || m.CustomerTitle == customerTitles[1]); // and so on
```

Here is the code for the filter building:

```
var titleFilterList = customerTitles.Select(title => String.Format("(CustomerTitle eq {0})", title));
var titleFilter = String.Join(" or ", titleFilterList);
var customers = Odata.CustomerService.AddQueryOption("$filter", titleFilter).Execute().ToList(); // you may have to cast this.
```

There is another option to do the same in a strongly typed manner using a nice extension method and building a dynamic Expression based predicate. Follow the steps from here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/07/17/set-based-operations-in-ado-net-data-services.aspx

Comment: Contains construct is now supported starting [v7.8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/changelog/odatalib-7x#odatalib-781-release). But apparently, it only works for array of strings, and NOT list of strings.

Comment: That's good to know @janonimus. For users who missed the feature, the array part shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

The following extension method can be used  LINQ to perform OData queries that test if the value of a property is contained in a set similar to how `Contains` works with LINQ to EF. It is based on the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/07/17/set-based-operations-in-ado-net-data-services.aspx) provided in Raja Nadar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22894789/1141360), specifically the comment at the end by Nick.

```
public static IQueryable<T> WherePropertyIsIn<T, TSet>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    IEnumerable<TSet> set,
    Expression<Func<T, TSet>> propertyExpression
) {
    var filterPredicate = set.Select(value => Expression.Equal(propertyExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(value)))
        .Aggregate<Expression, Expression>(Expression.Constant(false), Expression.Or);

    var filterLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filterPredicate, propertyExpression.Parameters.Single());

    return query.Where(filterLambdaExpression);
}
```

Usage:

```
var allowed_states = getAllowedStates();
var maxPopulation = getMaxPopulation();

// Instead of...
var cities = context.Cities.Where(c => allowed_states.Contains(c.State) && c.Population <= maxPopulation);

// Use...
var cities = context.Cities.Where(c => c.Population <= maxPopulation).WherePropertyIsIn(allowed_states, c => c.Cities);
```

Note that you must have a separate `Where` call (as shown above) if you wish to filter by more than `WherePropertyIsIn` allows. It would be nice if this could be combined into a single `Where` but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into issues with Timothy's solution when using it against Configuration Manager's OData service. CM utilises WML internally and therefore is even more limited in what can be parsed.

I have changed the code to generate a bit 'cleaner' query, which avoid using `Expression.Constant(false)` as aggregate base -> it produces 0 that is not accepted by WML

```
  public static IQueryable<T> WherePropertyIsIn<T, TSet>(this IQueryable<T> query,
            IEnumerable<TSet> valuesList, Expression<Func<T, TSet>> propertySelector)
        {
            if (valuesList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(valuesList));

            //if there are no values, no entities can fullfil the condition -> return empty
            if (!valuesList.Any())
                return Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();

            //create a check for each value
            var filters = valuesList.Select(value => Expression.Equal(propertySelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value)));

            //build an expression aggregating checks with OR, use first check as starter (could be '0', but doesn't get mapped to WML) 
            var firstCheck = filters.First();
            //we could duplicate first check, but why not just skip it
            var filterPredicate = filters.Skip(1).Aggregate(firstCheck, (Func<Expression, Expression, Expression>)Expression.Or);
            var filterLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filterPredicate, propertySelector.Parameters.Single());

            return query.Where(filterLambdaExpression);
           
        }
    }
```

A side effect is that when there are no values passed as argument, the query will immediately return an empty result, which may save time comparing to processing it by external service. At the same time it may be undesired if query is meant to actually run on server.